# If column a=0, then use column b, if column b=0, then use column c

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have 4 columns (A-D) and a fifth column (E) I want to have a valid value.
[image]

My logic for E2 is something like "if D2 is 0, then use C2, and if C2 is also 0, then use B2, and if B2 is again 0, then use A2"
Then I tried this formula: `= if(D2=0, C2, if(C2=0, B2,if(B2=0, A2), D2)`
sure it won't work..

Please help here! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
=IF(D2&""="0",IF(C2&""="0",IF(B2&""="0",A2,B2),C2),D2)&""
```

I have put the `&""` to make all value into string first, and compare with "0", in case you have put the something like `'0` in cell.

At the end, put `&""` to force the value in string

EDIT:
If no need to cater the text or value, you can just simple remove those `&""`

```
=IF(D2=0,IF(C2=0,IF(B2=0,A2,B2),C2),D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula.

```
 =IF(D1<>0,D1,IF(AND(D1=0,C1<>0),C1,IF(AND(D1=0,C1=0,B1<>0),B1,IF(AND(D1=0,C1=0,B1=0,A1<>0),A1,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Why `AND(D1=0,C1<>0)`, etc.?  If you get to that point, D1 must be zero, so you don't need to check it again.

Comment: As you see attached photo, there is data in column `D`

Comment: What I mean is, the second `if` statement will never be run unless D1 is 0.  Therefore you don't need to check that D1=0 again.